# Do I need to declare a class for using HQL?

Tags: hibernate, hql

I am migrating some of the application logic from JDBC to Hibernate. Using JDBC there are many simple insert, update and select statements and I am trying to use HQL for this purpose.

As an example, using JDBC, following is the query

```
select * from tab where property =<given value>
```

I used the HQL like this

```
session.createQuery(query).setString("property", "some prop value");
```

When I am running the code, I keep getting the error saying

> "org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: tab is
>   not mapped"

Do I need to declare a POJO class for each of the query that I am planning to execute using hql?

Comment: What do you want to do with the `setString("property","some prop value")` method? It seems to be `setParameter(String string, Object o)` instead. You execute HQL on entity classes. You need them. There is no question.

Comment: I agree.. proceeding with the POJO approach.

Answer (score 0):

Using of Hibernate:

To use a table in HQL query in clause FROM you must map your table as a bean

Example 1:

```
String hql = "SELECT e FROM " + MyEntity.class.getName() + " e ";
```

MyEntity class must map a real table to access on your DB (you can use JPA notation or XML notation, I prefer the second)

You can not have a real table but redirect your query result in a bean not mapped using a costructor of your bean.

Example 2:

```
String hql = "SELECT new " + MyNotMappedEntity.class.getName() + 
"(e.field1, e.field2)" +
" FROM " + MyEntity.class.getName() + " e ";
```

In Example 2 your class MyNotMappedEntity must have a properly constructor with two parameter of the same type of two fields passed.

Tell me it's ok or you want more info.